# Is it RESTFul to call a Represention of a resource which has a calculated value ( UI oriented , Client Specific )

Tags: spring, rest, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, frontend

In Pragmatic RESTFul API i accept below as response for a Employee Resource

/employee/1

```
{
  "name":"Foo",
  "dob": "2020-06-21"
}
```

Just assume I want DOB property in different fashion in my UI/Client which i cannot achieve easily in my client. So I modified my response as like my ***CLIENT DEMANDS*** :

```
{
  "name":"Foo",
  "dob": "2020-06-21",
  "dobShort": "Jun 21, 2020",
  "dobLong" : "Sunday, June 21, 2020"
}
```

My doubt is not about Date format or Customizing a response, I want to know is it RESTFul to call a response which shares a ***calculated** / **UI Dependent** / **Client oriented*** values.

Do I need to worry about client factors while designing a REST response.
I agree date format may be silly to do in back-end. But, what if it something difficult to achieve in Front-End and it not directly relevant to any resources.

Do my REST Response need to care about Client Specific Factors ?

Am i missing any well known REST compliance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know is it RESTFul to call a response which shares a calculated / UI Dependent / Client oriented values.

Yes, it is.

REST cares about [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and [representations](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2); but is indifferent to the fine grained implementation details.  In particular, REST absolutely does not care that some parts of the representation are stored, and other parts are calculated.

And that's largely the point - on the web, every server looks like a dumb document store, but that's because we have uniform agreement about the semantics of the messages used, not because we have uniform agreement about implementation.

REST does not care about whether or not a representation carries redundant information.

> Do my REST Response need to care about Client Specific Factors ?

"Need to"?  no, it isn't required.  Also, it isn't forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

In your RESTful API design, it is unwise to have more than one properties in the Response body depict the same data in different format. It would be wiser to let the client parse the data according to the way they need. In the sample scenario you mentioned, the REST server can send the date in ISO8601 format and the client shall convert it into the version that they would like to.

You can support for various formats of content though, which the client may ask for via the Accept headers ( this is related to content negotiation ). You can also allow pagination if the result set for a GET all call is too large to be handled in a single call. But if there are any client specific computational requirements, it is better to shift that work to the client side. This can be a handy if the RESTful server is going to have multiple applications communicating to it as clients in future. Adding client specific things at server end would also contribute to tight coupling, which is not something that you may be happy for, while looking at the application from a long-term perspective.

Comment: Your answer says "But if there are any client specific computational requirements, it is better to shift that work to the client side."

So, Shall I assume or conclude like "there is no rule in Rest which prevents you to having client specific thing in server end, But it is better to having in client itself"  ? 

What you do in case of dead lock situation where you want your server help to arrive something expensive for one your particular client alone  ? This is my exact indecision.

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is right. There is no hard and fast rule. You can handle corner cases by providing separate API for specific client. For instance, you can have it as https://ipaddress:portnumber/V2/pathtoyourresource. This shall be used by only that client who is in need of extra computational help from the server.